# Accidently deleted /usr/bin/python3

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, python3

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and had previously compiled python 3.8 from source, which was getting confusing when the default from Ubuntu is now python 3.8. So I manually removed the compiled from source binary. Only in the process I accidentally deleted the systems version of python3.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
[~] $ sudo dpkg -i python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 568603 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
running python pre-rtupdate hooks for python3.8...
Unpacking python3 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) over (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.8 (>= 3.8.2-1~); however:
  Package python3.8 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
```

That didn't work so I tried via apt

```
[~] $ sudo apt install -f python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst: 9: /usr/bin/python3.8: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.8 (--configure):
 installed python3.8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.8 (>= 3.8.2-1~); however:
  Package python3.8 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while proc
essing:
 python3.8
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As I understand it apt has a dependency of python3? Is that true? Any solutions to forcing a re-install of python3?

**Update**: based on comment

```
sudo dpkg --configure python3.8
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst: 9: /usr/bin/python3.8: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.8 (--configure):
 installed python3.8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.8
```

**Update 2**

Running `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst` via `sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst` (not sure it there's a different way to run it) didn't produce any output. However looking at the file shows it's calling python3.8 which was accidentally removed.

```
tom@computer[~] $ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst
#! /bin/sh

set -e

case "$1" in
    configure)
    files=$(dpkg -L libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 | sed -n '/^\/usr\/lib\/python3.8\/.*\.py$/p')
    if [ -n "$files" ]; then
    /usr/bin/python3.8 -E -S /usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py $files
    if grep -sq '^byte-compile[^#]*optimize' /etc/python/debian_config; then
        /usr/bin/python3.8 -E -S -O /usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py $files
    fi
    else
    echo >&2 "python3.8: can't get files for byte-compilation"
    fi
esac

exit 0 

tom@computer[~] $ /usr/bin/python3.8
-bash: /usr/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I did read the output thanks... updated description with result of that

Comment: Now the key output is `installed python3.8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127`. Error code 127 usually means command-not-found. In this case, some command in the package's post-install script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.8.postinst) was not found. Look at that file -- make sure it's not garbled or corrupted. Try running that script manually and see what error message you get.

Comment: Tried that, see second update. Seems like a chicken & egg problem where apt assumes python3 is there.

Comment: Correct. Apt requires a complete Python 3 install. dpkg does not require python3 at all...but dpkg won't automatically handle dependencies. It's possible to use dpkg to reinstall all of the Python 3 dependencies. There are only five or six needed to resurrect apt, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You install a version that is too old by one release. The `python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2` it needs at least `python3.8 (>= 3.8.2-1~)` which is in my cache as the oldest available to me. For the configured error if you run into it again. Use `dpkg --configure -a` to configure the not configured packages. Your options are to download the last version I show below from Ubuntu's servers or the newest 3.8.5 that is up to date with your installation. You can search on the packages site for Ubuntu or use apt if possible to get the needed files.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# apt-cache policy python3.8
python3.8:
  Installed: 3.8.5-1~20.04
  Candidate: 3.8.5-1~20.04
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.5-1~20.04 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
root@zeus-H370M:~# cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Then there is always the manual solution unpack with `ar x file.deb` move the files into place if needed and edit the status file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to tell it is installed and try it once more. If extracted at the / I think will put them in the proper place to be certain, I would create directory and extract in that then move into place.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue, I updated the question with the outcome from that.

Comment: Added a manual way for you to try.